# Stop and resume a running function on javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi,

this is my code now:

```
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("areaslide");
  var y = document.getElementsByClassName("arealink");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.opacity = "0";
    y[i].style.backgroundColor = "";  
  }
  myIndex++;
  if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    
  x[myIndex-1].style.opacity = "100";
  y[myIndex-1].style.backgroundColor = "#ad9463";  
  setTimeout(carousel, 3000); // Change image every 2 seconds

}
```

this function starts executing as the page loads but I need it to stop when mouse comes over this element:

```
<a href="" class="arealink" onmouseover="stopfunction()" onmouseout="resumefunction()">some link</a>
```

and the function should resume onmouseout. How should I do it?

Thank you.

Comment: wrap the action part of the function in a conditional based on flag and toggle that flag on hover

Comment: you mean like `function carousel(stop)` `if (stop === 1) {clearTimeout(carousel);} `

Comment: correct, the answer from @pydude below sums it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `stopFunction` and `resumeFunction` can set a flag on for whether or not to keep cycling. Then, your carousel function can check if it should cycle or not.

```
var doCycle=true;
function stopFunction(){
    doCycle=false;
}

function resumeFunction(){
    doCycle=true;
}

function carousel() {
  if(doCycle){//if you are not cycling, do not change the picture. But it still checks again in 3 seconds.
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("areaslide");
    var y = document.getElementsByClassName("arealink");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].style.opacity = "0";
      y[i].style.backgroundColor = "";  
    }
    myIndex++;
    if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    
    x[myIndex-1].style.opacity = "100";
    y[myIndex-1].style.backgroundColor = "#ad9463";  
  }
  setTimeout(carousel, 3000); // Change image every 3 seconds

}
```

Answer (score 2):

After doing some research, I'd recommend using an `interval` for this purpose.

It repeats something for you, so you don't have to start your `timeout` recursively.
You can then simply clear the `interval` on `mouseenter` using `window.clearInterval` and then set a new interval on `mouseleave`, like this:

```js
var myInterval;

function move() {
  document.getElementById('carousel').classList.toggle('moved');
}

function start() {
  myInterval = window.setInterval(move, 2000);
}

function stop() {
  window.clearInterval(myInterval);
}

start();
```

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#carousel {
  width: 200%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 0;
  transition: margin-left 0.2s;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #646464 50%, #ccc 50%);
}

#carousel.moved {
  margin-left: -100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="carousel" onmouseenter="stop()" onmouseleave="start()"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can exit the function using a return statement, and only execute part of the function if a condition is set.

```
function carousel() {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("areaslide");
  var y = document.getElementsByClassName("arealink"); 

  if (nostop) {
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.opacity = "0";
        y[i].style.backgroundColor = "";  
      }
      myIndex++;
      if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    
      x[myIndex-1].style.opacity = "100";
      y[myIndex-1].style.backgroundColor = "#ad9463";  
      setTimeout(carousel, 3000); // Change image every 2 seconds
      }
    else {
        return null
}

}
```